# g++ static string member causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++

I own a static library "My.a", my static library is a pure C library. My static library internally links to another C++ static library "Yours.a" , So whoever consumes my library has to link against libstdc++ since my library has dependency on libstdc++.

There is a program "Final_Exec" which is linking dynamically against libstdc++, and also linking statically to my library.

When I am launching this executable, and while this executable finished executing and calles exit, I get a segmentation fault and the following stack trace

```
*** glibc detected *** ./stage-O/bin/amd64/CATS: double free or corruption        (!prev): 0x0000000016846b80 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x2ac1f98e54af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x2ac1f98e97ab]
/slowfs/swe82/abhish_temp/clientstore/v35/stage-  O/lib/amd64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x1f)[0x2ac1f91820af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(exit+0xe5)[0x2ac1f98a7255]

~basic_string destructor is throwing exception while freeing the global string.
```

Just to troubleshoot if I remove the dependency on the library "Yours.a" from my library and then link it to the executable, I don't get the segmentation fault.

This final_executable is also linking against other shared libraries like boost, QT etc which also has dependency on libstdc++ and libstdc++ is linked dynamically in these shared libs.

Can anyone provide any reasonable conclusion for this problem?

Sorry for not providing any code, but I don't own any of this code, I just own the "My.a" library which is C library, but I think the issue in the mix with C++ libraries somewhere.

Comment: If you can't share the C++ code, then your best bet is to reproduce the problem with simpler code that you can share.  We aren't likely to be able to help much with a problem like this given just a general description and an error message.

Comment: I understand, Thanks.
One general Question is there any known issue, if the C++ library which is statically linked to an EXE, and This EXE is linking dynamically to a shared library which is a dependent library for my static library?